# MongoDB $expr expression

Tags: mongodb

I have collection where I want to filter by comparing 2 fields with modification on one of them.
I'm using $where for this filter now (The fields are lastTime and Threshold) and the $where filter look like this

```
this.lastTime < new Date(ISODate().getTime() - 1000 * 60 * this.Threshold)
```

I want to change the usage of $where to $expr,
I tried something like this but it doesn't work (If change $Threshold to hardcoded number it's working) is this even possible?

```
db.getCollection("test").find({ "$expr" : { "$lt" : ["$lastTime", new Date(ISODate().getTime() - 1000 * 60 * NumberInt("$Threshold"))] } })
```

I want to change $where to $expr so I won't use javascript engine is there any way to achieve it (Mongo 4.2) i'm trying to avoid Aggregation also?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

When working with date&times I recommend [moment.js](https://momentjs.com/docs/).

This one should work:

```
db.getCollection("test").find(
   { "lastTime": { $lt: moment().subtract(this.Threshold, "minutes").toDate() } }
)
```

Comment: You have to download and install the library. Then you can load it, e.g. by `load('/home/moment-with-locales.js')`