# how do i get two values ​that are not equal? in mongodb

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, schema

I need to select the ones whose two data are not equal in themselves. I can't find how to use it.
My code schema example.

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose')

var Schema = mongoose.Schema

var houseschema = new Schema({
  price: {type: Number, required: true},
  owner: {type:Number, required:true},
  building_floor: {type:Number, required: true},
  floor: {type:Number, required: true},
  rooms: {type:Number, required:true},
  in_square: {type:Number, required:true},
  repair: {type:Number, required:false, default:0},
  furniture: {type:Number, required:false, default:0},
  district: {type: String, required: true, maxlength: 100, minlength: 3},
  exchange: {type:Number, required:false, default:0},
  description: {type: String, required: true, maxlength: 100, minlength: 3},
  owner_name: {type: String, required: true, maxlength: 100, minlength: 3}, 

 created_date: {type: Date, default: Date.now}
},{collection:'houses'})

var houses = mongoose.model('houses', houseschema)

module.exports = houses
```

How do I get the unequals of `floor` and `building_floor`?

Comment: Does this help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60525650/mongodb-expr-expression

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use mongodb's aggregation framework:
`match` stage will help you compare two fields within the same document.

```
houses.aggregate([{
  $match: {
    $expr: {
      $ne: [
        '$building_floor', '$floor',
      ],
    },
  },
}]);
```